# Is there a way to enable/disable input/textarea with list items in a list

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I have a list of items and when clicked on any list-item, the data is shown in an input/textarea. The behavior expected is when list-item is selected, the textarea in my case, should be disabled. But when I click edit, a call to show is also going. So, edit and show note methods are being called due to which the disable functionality isn't working.

I know the show is getting called because of edit/delete and all the three(show, edit, delete) are linked on the list but is there a way not to call show when edit/delete is clicked clicked?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{"id":1, "name":'One', "description":'Oklahoma'},
                  {"id":2, "name":'Two', "description":'Utah'},
                  {"id":3, "name":'Three', "description":'Southampton'}];
      $scope.selected;

      $scope.showitem = (id) => {
        console.log('show item')
        $scope.selected = fetchSelecteditem(id);
        $scope.selected.enable = false;
      }

      $scope.edititem = (id) => {
        console.log('edit item')
        $scope.selected = fetchSelecteditem(id);
        $scope.selected.enable = true;
      }

      $scope.deleteitem = (id) => {
        console.log('delete item')
        $scope.selected = fetchSelecteditem(id);
        $scope.selected.enable = false;
      }

      let fetchSelecteditem = (id) => {
        return $scope.items.find(x => (x.id === id));
      }
    });
```

Please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0hr6nxtk/5. You can relate to the scenario in the console of the fiddle.

Please tell me how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<li ng-click="showitem(item.id)"><span>{{item.name}}</span>
```

you can move the click event into the span:

```
<span ng-click="showitem(item.id)">{{item.name}}</span>
```

Comment: No, that won't work. There is an ng-repeat on the ul. I have tried that workaround before.

Comment: If you wanted to not show the item when editing or deleting, then it's working. It doesn't matter if there is a ng-repeat. Check out here: https://jsfiddle.net/5rfge12z/ or explain better what you want to achieve. Another thing that you need to change is: ng-disabled="!selected.enable"